# Don't use correct grammar topic

Tags: discussion

It's my first question about my English, I usually use basic world and structure for ask some technique question for other stackoverflown users but i never can use true structure or grammar.

I really wanna improve write and read skill i tried many many way but still same.

I'm open any type of idea solution thanks.

Comment: Expose yourself to English more by reading books in English, watching movies, etc. Also, find a textbook on English grammar with exercises. Books written by a guy named Murphy are popular.

Comment: You could start by improving your typing. The pronoun "I" is never spelled in lower case, and avoid words like "wanna" when you can use a more formal alternative like "want to". (This comment is meant to be helpful, not critical.) I really do wish you all the best as you hone your English skills.